# How to get the recent date value of one label from Prometheus and show it on Grafana

Tags: date, label, prometheus, grafana

I am working on Grafana. For one metric, I would like to visualize the recent date value of one label from Prometheus.

exp:

```
metric_processed_date{"process_date"="23-03-2023 14:35:25","job":"j1"}
metric_processed_date{"process_date"="20-02-2023 14:35:25","job":"j1"}
```

I would like to visualize the date "23-03-2023 14:35:25"

Comment: Could you clarify: you get both metrics from your query, but want to show only one on your panel? Also, what panel do you use?

Comment: Hello, I am using a table Panel. I found a solution for this problem:
I used a simple query metric_processed_date{job="my-job"} and I applied some trasnformation: 
 On options: I choose Table Format / Type: instant
On Transform: 
1) organize fields to keep only process_date label 
2) Function Reduce / Calculations First*
3) Organize fields again to hide Field column 
4) convert Field Type to change the format of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a table Panel.

I found a solution for this problem:

I used a simple query `metric_processed_date{job="my-job"}` and applied some transformation:

On options:

- Format: Table
- Type: instant

On Transform:

1. Organize fields - to keep only process_date label
2. Function Reduce / Calculations First*
3. Organize fields - again, to hide Field column
4. Convert Field Type - to change the format of date

Thank you !